# How do I get resized thumbnails?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I'm getting post thumbnails by calling `the_post_thumbnail(array(400,300), true);` However, this displays the fullsize featured image, just resized with the html "height" and "width" tags. This is not good for loading times. I've tried regenerating thumbnails and that doesn't make a difference.

Isn't there a way to get thumbnails that have been resized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code is calling the full size image as you mention and resizing to the dimensions you feed into the array.

I've answered this question before [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128167/exact-image-sizes/), but the basic idea is that you'll want to use [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in your `functions.php` to tell Wordpress you'd like it to create a new image size when you upload images.

Then you'll need to use [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) to call the image into your template.

Comment: One has to regenerate the thumbnails again (for previously uploaded images) after adding new image sizes.

Comment: Good point, I mention it in my linked answer, but was unsure of whether I should just duplicate my exact answer.